# Issues with .JSON file conversion and CSV manipulation in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

sorry for the long post! I'm a bit Python-illiterate, so please bear with me:

I am working on a project that uses extracted Fitbit resting heart-rate data to compare heart-rate values between a series of years.
The fitbit data exports as a .json file that I am attempting to convert to .csv for further analysis.
I pulled a script from github that converts .json files to .csv-formatted files, however when inputing the resting heart rate data I am running into a few troubles.

**Sample lines from .json:**

```
[{
"dateTime" : "09/30/16 00:00:00",
"value" : {
"date" : "09/30/16",
"value" : 76.83736383927637,
"error" : 2.737363838373737
}
```

**Section of GitHub code that transforms nested frame into columns:**

```
# reading json into dataframes
resting_hr_df = get_json_to_df(file_list=resting_hr_file_list).reset_index()

# Heart rate contains a sub json that are explicitly converted into column
resting_hr_df['date'] = resting_hr_df['value'].transform(lambda x: make_new_df_value(x, 'date'))
resting_hr_df['value'] = resting_hr_df['value'].transform(lambda x: make_new_df_value(x, 'value'))
resting_hr_df['error'] = resting_hr_df['value'].transform(lambda x: make_new_df_value(x, 'error'))
resting_hr_df = resting_hr_df.drop(['value', 'index'], axis=1)
```

There are two variables named 'value' and I think this is causing the issue.

When using the transform function in pandas to assign variable names for the nested dataframe keys, the second ‘value’ values store as 0 in the .csv file.
How should I store the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this is a nested json file. The solution is to load the json file with `json` and then load it into pandas with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('filename.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

resting_hr_df = pd.json_normalize(data)
resting_hr_df
```

Output `resting_hr_df`:

```
|    | dateTime          | value.date   |   value.value |   value.error |
|---:|:------------------|:-------------|--------------:|--------------:|
|  0 | 09/30/16 00:00:00 | 09/30/16     |       76.8374 |       2.73736 |
```

Comment: Absolutely! And to save the dataframe as `csv`:  `resting_hr_df.to_csv("out.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')` .

Answer (score 0):

You can easy solve this method using default pandas function like read_json .

```
df = pd.read_json('abc.json', orient='index')
data = df.to_csv(index=False)
print(data)
```

it can be easy and helpful to solve this problem by convert json to csv file